# Visual Studio Code - run selection in python terminal doesn't work properly with long selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue with running selection in Python terminal. When i attempt to execute multiple lines of code at once (100+ lines) the terminal splits the code at a certain point resulting in errors with that specific line or block of code.
It seems like there may be a limitation based on the number of characters.

For instance, if the line 166 contains **print("test")**, it appears that the terminal might interpret it as for example **print("t**, leading to errors. This behavior seems to occur due to the terminal breaking the line at a certain point, causing unintended code execution.

I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: what if you disable python repl smart send?

Comment: The problem occurs with and without python repl smart send.